# corrupted ubuntu installation

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, nvidia

I've got a new notebook with Windows 10. I installed Ubuntu 19.04 but had an issue with Nvidia 1050 graphic card.

So I decided to install Ubuntu 18.04 but I manually removed 19.04 partitions/volumes from Windows.

Now, when I press the start button, grub starts. I also created live USB with Rufus but during the installation of 18.04, the screen is blocked after a few seconds. Same thing if I try live version.

I read an error regarding AGP but I'm not sure.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

Solved! I installed again ubuntu 19.04 in safe graphics mode.

It seems that also Nvidia now works. But, I have another issue: after login Ubuntu is blocked. May be issue with graphic card driver..but I didn't check yet

Should I do a new thread?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, make a new qustion for the new problem.